# Why doesn't this program terminate?

Tags: java, executorservice

New to java, but I can't figure out why this program doesn't terminate:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
        ex.submit(() -> { System.out.println("."); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `ex.shutdown()` on your Executor. The program doesn't stop because it is waiting on work that never comes. Calling shutdown tells the executor to stop it's threads and hopefully it should solve your problem.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!